# return list of class object in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, binding

I have a class as below.

```
namespace WpfApplication2
{
    class TaskItem
    {
        private string name;
        private string item;
        private string description;
        private int priority;
        public string Name
        {
            get
            { return name; }
            set
            { this.name = value; }
        }

        public string Item
        {
            get
            {
                return item;
            }
            set
            {
                this.item = value;
            }
        }
        public string Description
        {
            get
            {
                return String.Format("{0} {1}",name,item);
            }
        }
        public int Priority
        {
            get
            {
                return priority;
            }
            set
            {
                this.priority = value;
            }
        }

        public TaskItem()
        {


        }

    }
}
```

I want to return the list of this class object to my wpf application as below.

```
<WpfApplication2:TaskItem x:Key="taskItem"/>
```

After that I will bind this to ListBox. How could I return this list of class object? Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: More information on what you're trying to do would be helpful in providing an answer that meets your end-goal... rather than one that just technically works. But yet I've an answer for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xaml declaration is for a single TaskItem, not a collection.  You need a collection to bind to the ItemsSource of your ListBox.  See the notes on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28VS.90%29.aspx)  about the limitations of a xaml only solution using ObservableCollection.  You will probably want to create a list in code to bind to the ListBox, or create your own class that inherits from ObservableCollection and then create an instance of that class in you xaml instead.

Comment: Actually, I want to create two data template and will select the template using the TemplateSelector.

Comment: @David, you still need to be working with a collection of items at some point as the TemplateSelector will be applied to each of the items in the underlying collection.

Comment: Yes, this msdn link is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to create a `List<TaskItems>` and set this as the DataContext ?

Answer (score 0):

Technically possible.. with something similar to this (Replace Observable collection with List and my:Person with your custom class). 
See also: [Generics support was added recently to XAML](http://windowsclient.net/blogs/rob_relyea/archive/2009/06/01/xaml-using-generic-types-in-xaml-2009.aspx)

```
<Window>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <ObservableCollection x:TypeArguments="my:Person">
            <my:Person FirstName="Tom" LastName="Holiday" />
            <my:Person FirstName="Joan" LastName="Holiday" />
        </ObservableCollection>
    </Window.DataContext>
    …
</Window>
```